# QComboBox background color

Tags: css, qt, background-color, qcombobox

I have created a Qt HMI with QtDesigner and ui files. My QComboBox doesn't have the same background color in the designer and in real:

Designer:

[image]

Real life:

[image]

I am under Windows 7. Maybe it is OS dependent but I would like to have a white background.

I tried:

```
comboBox->setStyleSheet("QComboBox { background-color: white; }");
```

but it also paints the right arrow.

Any explanation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `QPalette::Base` does not change the background of the `QComboBox`.

Instead I've used:

```
QPalette palette = ui->combo->palette();
palette.setColor(QPalette::Active, QPalette::Button, Qt::white);
palette.setColor(QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::Button, Qt::white);
ui->combo->setPalette(palette);
```

and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Is the combo empty?

Try adding some elements and select one of them before running the "app".

Comment: No it is not empty. It contains elements.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing QPalette::Base to white? You can do it without using any stylesheet.

```
QComboBox box = new QComboBox();
QPalette p = box.palette();

p.setColor(QPalette::Active, QPalette::Base, Qt::white);
p.setColor(QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::Base, Qt::white);

box.setPalette(p);
```

Comment: No I've not tried yet. But it would be easier to change it directly from the Qt Designer. What's the point having ui files if the HMI is modified in a cpp file?